# How is the syntax of regular expression at bash?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, rhel

I created a regex that finally works for my case

```
:pkcs7-data\n.+\n\s+(.+?):
```

You can have a look how it works right here [REGEX101 link](https://regex101.com/r/wJ8uP6/1) It has to find the **first occurrence** of a certain significant number.

I built it using REGEX101 but I have to use it in a bash terminal. My idea is to use that regex in a grep command which gets as an input a file too.

```
grep -Po ':pkcs7-data\n.+\n\s+(.+?):' file.txt
```

My problem is that REGEX101 syntax I used doesn't fit for this bash

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

I lookep up some tool ([tool1](http://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp)) or files ([file1](http://www.ericagamet.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Erica-Gamets-GREP-Cheat-Sheet.pdf),[file2](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html), [file3](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/) ) I found but I'm still not able to get anything. I mean, every time I execute grep I don't get anything. I think, the problem must be in some symbols like "\n" or "+" but I'm not succeeding. If I execute something like

```
grep -Po ':pkcs7-data' file.txt
```

I got good results. Once I start with symbols like end of line begin the problems.

Comment: The issue is not with regular expressions per se, but that `bash` does not interpret `\n` as a literal newline character, nor does `grep`.

Comment: Also, for future reference: bash *also* has regular expressions, but in your question you are actually referring to `grep`'s regular expression syntax. GNU grep implements three different syntaxes: BRE, ERE and PCRE (only the first two are required by Posix grep), with some extensions (such as `\s` representing space characters). bash regexes are ERE format without extensions (afaik). BRE and ERE are documented in `man 7 regex` (among other places).

Comment: Additionally, just for reference, in FreeBSD the grep command does not include PCRE, but there is a "port" ([devel/pcre](http://freshports.org/devel/pcre)) that can be installed which provides `pcregrep`, with similar functionality to `grep -P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=" +|:"}/:pkcs7-data/{getline;getline;print $2;exit }' file.txt
```

`pcregrep` (if avaliable) is a nice tool to handle multiline `regex` but i'm can't find a way to get only the matched group:

```
pcregrep -M -o '(?<=:pkcs7-data)\n.+\n\s+(\d+)' file.txt
```

Comment: You solutions works almost perfect. With the regex I developed I got just one incidence and with yours I get two. If I have to get just 61, with the one you passed me I get 61 and 2861. Can you suggest me some **awk** syntax file or web?

Comment: I think I found it! Using **awk**:
`awk 'BEGIN{FS=" +|:"}/:pkcs7-data/{getline;getline;print $2;exit;}' file.txt`

This way, after first occurrence, awk stops and then I get what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Grep is a line based regular expression tool, it does not handle multi-line patterns like what you have. You should be using Perl or rework your problem into sed or awk.

Comment: I have to go to work, but you sound like a smart person, I am sure you will figure it out.

Comment: I appreciate your comment XD You should know that this is the third Stackoverflow account I open. They banned me two times because of my "silly" questions. Since then I learnt what and how to question. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rob and @klashxx I found a solution. As @Rob said

> "Grep is a line based regular expression tool, it does not handle
>   multi-line patterns like what you have. You should be using Perl or
>   rework your problem into sed or awk."

So grep was to be discarded. And after that, @klashxx added:

> An awk solution:
>
> `awk  'BEGIN{FS=" +|:"}/:pkcs7-data/{getline;getline;print $2}' file.txt`
>
> pcregrep (if avaliable) is a nice tool to handle multiline
>   regex but i'm can't find a way to get only the matched group:
>
> `pcregrep -M -o '(?<=:pkcs7-data)\n.+\n\s+(\d+)' file.txt`

I tried to solve it with **awk**. The only problem for me, with @klashxx awk solution it was that I just wanted to get the first occurrence. So I did a little research and find that awk `exit` stops awk execution. So after first occurrence, it would stop.

`awk  'BEGIN{FS=" +|:"}/:pkcs7-data/{getline;getline;print $2; exit;}' file.txt`

And now works. Thanks a lot for helping.

Kind regards,
Andrés-J. Cremades

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.